# Python Datacompy: How to get FULL comparison report?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Python code that compares 2 dataframes and spits out a comparison report.  There are different sections with 10 sample rows each of the differences.  I have searched long and hard to figure out how can I produce the FULL report?  Even if it's separate report for each of the sections.  **The question is:  instead of default sample comparison report, how can I get a full report (for each of the sections)?**

Comment: It sounds like your using pandas dataframes. Is that case? If so, you'll need to make a reproducible example as it's unclear what the issue is and what output you expect. I recommend giving this question (linked in the SO wiki for pandas) a read to learn how to create a good reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Correct, I am using panda dataframes.  I am comparing 2 dataframes and producing an output report (datacompy.report.compare()).  So in this report, there are several sections, each being a sample.  I would like the full dataset, not just the sample for each of the sections.  See this in the output report (the last section):  Sample Rows Only in Kona (First 10 Columns).  I want ALL rows.  Does this help in clarifying what my question/issue is?  Thank you for your comment to help get me going, been struggling for a while on this one....

Comment: Well, when I run a basic `datacompy` example, I do get a full report. So I don't even understand how you generate a partial report. Are did you try setting the sample rows parameter to an arbitrarily high number?

Comment: Maybe my dataset is too large (or much larger than yours)?  I did see the option to set sample rows in the output report, so my next attempt will be to set the sample row parameter number as high as it could be from the dataset.... that will at least provide more value than 10 rows.  Thank you so much for your input and assistance with this.  Still no real answer, but I think the workaround should get me what I need.  Thanks!!